# ubuntu: position of menu icon on the top menubar changes randomly

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

The position of icons in the menubar on the top of the ubuntu desktop changes randomly from time to time.

For example I had the user icon (the one with the logoff/shutdown sub menu) somewhere in the middle of the top menubar after installing. After a while it moved automatically to the end of the menubar.

Q1: How can I restore it to the initial position?
Q2: How can I prevent it from moving the icons as it likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try enabling **Locked Down** mode. This should prevent any changes to the panels until you modify the key again.

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gconf-editor`
- In the left pane, expand to **apps -> panel -> global**
- Enable the **Locked_Down** key.

If you enjoy a command-line approach, this is how you can save and import gconf settings:

- Run `gconftool-2 --dump /apps/panel > ~/settings/saved_panel_settings.entries` to save your panel settings
- Run `gconftool-2 --load ~/settings/saved_panel_settings.entries` to reload them
- Run `killall gnome-panel` to restart GNOME with your loaded settings

For an easy way to switch between layouts and save layouts, check out [**PanelSwitcher**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PanelSwitcher).

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Right click the moved item. Click the `Move` option. Untick "Lock to Panel" if necessary.

Comment: I have most things locked and they move around all the time.  Mostly has to do with changing resolutions, but the changes are not predictable in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

Q2.
See if you have *Expand* option set in panel properties. if not, then set it and check if the icons are moving.
Also I dont have any icons locked but they retain their place. Unlock all the items in the panel and see if they move around.

Comment: `expand` is already enabled. Some of the Icons whre `locked` - and I have unlocked all of them now. No difference though.